# Does the Wordpress API work with multisite?

Tags: multisite, rest-api

I’ve found next to no information on whether the rest API works with Wordpress multisite setup. Does it?

Comment: Yes. You can use each sites homeurl with /wp-json/ and it works just as standalone does.

Comment: @DavidSword answering in the comments won't get you upvotes :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the REST API is in the same location, just append `/wp-json` to the end of a site/blogs URL and there it is

As for the network admin, at the moment there are no endpoints explicitly for multisite, so you can't use the REST API to create and destroy sites without building those endpoints yourself, but this may change in the future